# Density in function space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, density-function

Let $$A = \{ f\colon{\mathbb{R}^2} \to \mathbb{R}\} $$
be the set of all function with two varibles
and let $$B = \{ f(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)\} $$ represent the set of all function with two variables that can be written as the product of two separate functions.
The question is: is $B$ dense in $A$? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should specify also the metric you want to use for the density.

Comment: When we use variables separation method, we decompose the function on two function separate,, i want to know is ths allow in some way ?

Comment: To discuss density, you need a topology. What is the topology you are putting on $A$?

Comment: Ok...let it be the $ L^2 $ topology..

Comment: The $L^2$ topology does not include all functions. "Most" functions are non-measurable.